# Split Reference.cs in ServiceReferences

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wcf-data-services

Is there any way to split out reference.cs file present under Service References ?

Our reference.cs file has now size of around 2 MB and there are lots of code is still going to add at service end.

I am having problem in code merging since there are 4000 lines of code.

Comment: what problem/issue are you trying to solve by splitting the reference.cs? (is the UI "sluggish", the client proxy "slow" or ...)

Comment: It is automatically generated , so editing it in any way is wrong. To shrink it, you might use Portable Class Library to share common classes on both sides, and then less types are generated in that file.

Comment: Problem is merging the code in version control

Comment: 4000 lines of code in the `reference.cs`file?  Do you have a lot of methods, or a lot of data contracts?  If you have a lot of methods, I'd suggest breaking your service up into several services.  Another option (and my preferred method) would be to use `ChannelFactory<T>` and put the service contracts into a shared assembly that the service implementation and the client can both use.

Comment: actually services are in java so we cant do anything :(